# Ícone fica pequeno na notificação

Tags: java, android

Estou com uma notificação simples,porém o ícone não preenche toda a parte. Gerei ele através do Android Asset e coloquei cada resolução em sua respectiva pasta no mipmap.

Notificação Android 4.1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notificação Android 5.0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this).
                setTicker("BPF Denúncia")
                .setContentTitle("BPF Denúncia")
                .setContentText("Há Uma Nova Denúncia Contra Você!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
```

Como resolver para que preencha todo o espaço da Notificação ?

Comment: Pode mostrar um exemplo de como gostaria que fosse?

Comment: Queria que ele preenchesse toda a parte.Se eu tenho um ícone retangular,em vez de ele por o ícone dentro de outro,o icone em si preenchesse tudo,sem ficar borda nenhuma.,aqui um exemplo usando o mesmo ícone:https://s31.postimg.org/n07w0y6l7/image.png

Comment: Outro Exemplo,agora ele está fazendo isso:
https://s31.postimg.org/57goqfu0n/atual.png

o certo,seria isto:
https://s31.postimg.org/psvgicblj/novo.png

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir qual é o ícone grande da sua notificação com [`setLargeIcon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)). Se você não definir, o pequeno é usado no lugar e não cresce sozinho.

Comment: Obrigado,fiz isto e funcionou !